# How to make rounded corner cut-out using CSS?

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'd like to make something that looks like the below image using CSS:

[image]
 I'm at a total loss on how to do that. Might someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using two elements or one element and a pseudo-element:

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { position:relative; background-color:#333; padding:20px;
      margin:20px; float:left; }

div:before { content:""; display:block; padding:5px; background-color:#f60;
             border:2px solid white; position: absolute; top:-2px;
             right:-2px;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vv6Eb/

---

**Update:**

With `border-top-right-radius`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vv6Eb/1/

Or, `border-bottom-left-radius`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vv6Eb/4/

Comment: oh that's nice, can you add the rounding to the edges that face each other?

Comment: @Xander this worked because the background of the main body is white, what is there is a background image. you will have to use css3 after property

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="page">
         <div id="up">

        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <div id="logobody"></div>    
        </div>
        <div id="down">

        </div>

</div>​

#page{
    margin:30px auto;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px red thin;
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#logo{
   float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:white;
    margin-top:-70px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#up{

    width:80%;
    height:60px;
    border-radius-top:10px;
    background:gray;

}
#down{
    margin-top:-0px;
    margin-right:-10px;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background:gray;

}

#logobody{
    border:2px blue solid;
    margin :auto;
    width:85px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:0px;
    border-radius:7px;
}
​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/KPjty/)

Comment: -@afshin, thanks that's pretty nice too especially since pseudo elements like the one's in Xander's answer can't easily be controlled with javascript,

Answer (score 0):

Use float..http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

```
<div style="background-color:#000; height:500px; width:500px; margin-bottom:10px;">

<div style="background-color:#FFF; float:right; height:100px; width:100px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px;"></div>

</div>


<div style="background-color:#000; height:500px; width:500px; position:relative;">

<div style="background-color:#FFF; position:absolute; right:0px; height:100px; width:100px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px;"></div>

</div>​
```

Inline styles is not advisable so might wanna write the styles in your stylesheet file. Using float makes the texts wraps the div tag. The seconds code stacks